# Debug assertion from VS2019 with mongocxx calls and std:string

Tags: c++, mongo-cxx-driver

I'm developing an application in VC++ that links to a static lib of utility functions and also makes use of the mongocxx v3.6.5#2  driver. I'm getting:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: E:\MyApp\x64\Debug\MyApp.exe File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\heap\debug_heap.cpp Line: 996

Expression: __acrt_first_block == header
```

when a std:string object returned from a bson object goes out of scope. I've carefully compared the compiler / linker settings for my app project and my library project to make sure they are compatible. I suspect that mongocxx build is somehow incompatible.

Here's the simplest code sample that exhibits the problem. The assertion failure occurs when the function returns.

```
// OID to_string test
#include <bsoncxx/oid.hpp>

void Oid_str(void)
{
    bsoncxx::oid idAlarmId;
    std::string sAlarmId = idAlarmId.to_string();
}
```

The mongocxx driver was installed with vcpkg which lists it as:
mongo-cxx-driver:x64-windows                       3.6.5#2          MongoDB C++ Driver.

Some project properties on my projects that seem relevant:

```
Platform Toolset: Visual Studio 2019 (v142)
C++ Language Standard: ISO C++14
C Language Standard: Legacy MSVC
vcpkg Triplet x64-windows
Code Generation:
  Enable SEH Exceptions (/EHa)
  Runtime: Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)
```

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Runtime Library to Multi-Threaded Debug Dll (/MDd) on my app- and lib projects seems to do the trick.  While My app is still linking to my own static LIB, /MDd makes everything run smoothly under the debugger